# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath' -- when importing Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I am running a Keras model in a Jupyter Notebook and I tried to import Tensorflow in a second JN but I got a weird message which I replicated in my command prompt:

```
(tf2) C:\WINDOWS\system32>python
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug  9 2019, 18:34:13) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow
2019-11-01 13:19:19.434547: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_100.dll
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
ImportError: numpy.core._multiarray_umath failed to import
ImportError: numpy.core.umath failed to import
2019-11-01 13:19:19.819614: F tensorflow/python/lib/core/bfloat16.cc:675] Check failed: PyBfloat16_Type.tp_base != nullptr
```

What I can not understand is how it can be that I can run a Keras model in one JN and be unable to import Tensorflow in the command prompt or in another JN.

```
(tf2) C:\WINDOWS\system32>python
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug  9 2019, 18:34:13) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.path)
['', 'C:\\Users\\Alienware\\Anaconda3\\envs\\tf2\\python37.zip', 'C:\\Users\\Alienware\\Anaconda3\\envs\\tf2\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\Alienware\\Anaconda3\\envs\\tf2\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\Alienware\\Anaconda3\\envs\\tf2', 'C:\\Users\\Alienware\\Anaconda3\\envs\\tf2\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Users\\Alienware\\Anaconda3\\envs\\tf2\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\Users\\Alienware\\Anaconda3\\envs\\tf2\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\Alienware\\Anaconda3\\envs\\tf2\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
```

Comment: Show `import sys; print(sys.path)`

Comment: Do you have tensorflow installed in the environment your running your jupyter-notebook?

Comment: Yes, as you can see it is the environment tf2 in which I have installed tensorflow 2.  As I said I am currently fitting a model in another Jupyter Notebook using tensorflow 2.

Comment: @lguananaut:  See my updated post

Comment: There is no need to add `Your advice will be appreciated` to the footer of all of your questions. You've probably had ~100 removed by now.  Remember that the editors that try to keep this place tidy are volunteers. We may be foolish for taking on the task, but we believe in this community, for all its many faults. We would rather not have to clean up after users who add redundant and conversational material wilfully.